# ios ARC table bad access

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

for my table view I have the following going on (paraphrased)

## .h

```
@interface OptionsView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dataSource;
```

## .m

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        ...

        self.dataSource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:options, sections, sponsor,  nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(self.dataSource) {
        NSArray *ds = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSDictionary *d = [ds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        ActionBlock a = [d objectForKey:ACTION]; // <-- Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x802)
        if(a != nil) a();
    }
}
```

You can see that in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` but I'm not sure why. Because I'm using arc it isn't a zombie problem (already checked).

Using breakpoints I see that the `self.dataSource` exists after it's initialized, but not later when it's needed. It doesn't show up as `<nil>` either, it's just white space. Also, this works in debug but not in release so what does that mean?

** EDIT adding a screenshot **

You will notice that neither `ds` or `d` show up.. odd?
[image: xcode debug]

Comment: This is probably not a fix but with ARC its typical to use weak/strong rather than assign/retain for properties

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same in xcode, but I know from developing in Visual Studio as well, debug symbols in release builds are not at all reliable

Comment: Can you log the values of `ds` and `d`?  Another help would be to wrap the failing line in a @try/@catch block and examine the exception's description and callStackSymbols.

Comment: Also if it's crashing on [d objectForKey:ACTION]; then "self.dataSource" and "ds" should still exist.

Comment: @all screenshot added. It will likely add some clarity to my situation.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the absence of ds or d _after_ the crash. Try putting in breakpoints and examine them before the crash. Have you tried putting a breakpoint before the crash and looking at the contents of ds and d then? Or put in NSLog statements? It would be fascinating to see the NSLog(@"d=%@", d) results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's two places I can see that might cause the problem.  First, what is `ACTION`?  Is it some sort of NSString?  Just want to make sure that you're using a valid key object.  Second, (and more likely the problem), it looks like `ActionBlock` is some kind of code block you're storing in a collection array.  Are you copying that block before you store it in the array/dictionary?  You must copy any block you intend on keeping around (storing) longer than the scope it was created in.  This is easy to do.  For example:

```
void (^NewBlock)(void) = [^{
    ....code....
} copy];
```

Alternately:

```
void (^NewBlock)(void) = ^{
    ....code....
};

[dictionary setObject:[NewBlock copy] forKey:ACTION]; //Assuming #define ACTION @"action"
```

This copies it onto the heap so that it can be stored.  If you don't copy it, you'll get BAD_EXC_ACCESS anytime you try to reference the block outside the scope it was created in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you´re using a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController. If I remember correctly, you have to go to the inspector and drag the delegate and datasource from the tableView to the UIViewController. I don´t remember exactly and I´m not on my computer but I´m sure I did it several times before I began to use a UITableViewController for every tableView I have.

Oh, and i wouldn´t use dataSource as a name for your array. Just to prevent naming conflicts.

Comment: Any object can be the datasource and delegate for a table view. You don't need a table view controller.

Comment: Yes, of course any object can be. I'm just saying that whatever these objects are, tableView has to know about them. That's why the connections have to be done. Again, it's been a long time since I did it that way, so  I might be rusty.